# Maven doesn't see some external dependencies in a multi-module project

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

I'm working on a project which has a parent pom.xml, a Java module in the project with some non-Java modules (using some Maven plugins).

I'm trying to add these dependencies (tried both the parent pom.xml and the module's pom.xml):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Then import these in one of my classes:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;
```

The IDE highlights "lambda" in red.

Maven build also fails:

"Dependency problems found",
"package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime does not exist",
"package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events does not exist".

The artifacts are fetched successfully. I see the jars in the local repo. Looked into the jars, - the packages are there.

Tried to delete the local repo and fetching all the libraries over again, - this didn't help.

Other dependencies are working OK, including some other libraries for AWS (S3, etc).

What is going on with these AWS Lambda dependencies? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Tried it and created a [small project](https://github.com/hwirnsberger/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/aws-lamda). It works just fine. Maybe you want to compare it.

Comment: Another detail: we use Artifactory, not a normal Maven repository. Our project has some dependencies and now I cannot add any new dependency to it! I add Apache Commons CLI dependency to the module's pom.xml file, just as an experiment (as a random 3rd party library), - and the build fails. I remove it and the build is working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved some time ago. I've forgotten to comment here. I've found out that there were some errors in the code and some source files were in wrong places (because there were Java/Kotlin transitions involved). In this case, the error messages from Maven were misleading, they did not reflect the real reasons of the errors. When we made several corrections in the code, the build was successful.